# jQuery .next() not returning next element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to use jQuery's .next() function to get the next element with `class="inputfield"` but all I'm getting is `[]`.

If you click on the empty cell the input element is displayed (function click_td(td_id)/ open_input(inputObj)).

When exiting the element it disappears leaving the text (function close_input(inputObj)).

By pressing tab I want to move to the next element (function next_cell(inputObj)).

Thanks,
Aba

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/_inc/jquery/jquery.js"></script> 
    <style type="text/css">
    .inputfield{        
        display: none;
    }
    </style>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="1" width="50%">      
        <tr>
            <td width="15%">Name</td>
            <td width="35%" onclick="click_td(this)" id="1_1"><span id="si1_1" style=""></span><input type="text" onblur="close_input(this);" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode==13) return false;if (event.keyCode==9) return next_cell(this)" size="25" value="" name="name" id="i1_1" class="inputfield"></td>
            <td width="15%">E-mail</td>
            <td width="35%" onclick="click_td(this)" id="1_2"><span id="si1_2"></span><input type="text" onblur="close_input(this);" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode==13) return false;if (event.keyCode==9) return next_cell(this)" size="25" value="" name="email" id="i1_2" class="inputfield"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Phone</td>
            <td onclick="click_td(this)" id="2_1"><span id="si2_1"></span><input type="text" onblur="close_input(this);" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode==13) return false;if (event.keyCode==9) return next_cell(this)" size="25" value="" name="phone" id="i2_1" class="inputfield"></td>        
            <td>Type:<br>
            </td><td onclick="click_td(this)" id="2_2"><span id="si2_2"></span>
                <select onblur="close_input(this);" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode==13) return false;if (event.keyCode==9) return next_cell(this)" name="article_type" id="i2_2" class="inputfield">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option>Buying Guide</option>
                    <option>Announcement</option>
                    <option>Hands-on Review</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

    <script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    <!--
    function click_td(td_id){
        var inputObj = document.getElementById('i' + td_id.id);
        open_input(inputObj)    
    }

    function open_input(inputObj){
        var spanObj = document.getElementById('s' + inputObj.id)    
        inputObj.style.display = 'block';
        spanObj.style.display = 'none';
        inputObj.focus();
    }

    function close_input(inputObj){
        var spanObj = document.getElementById('s' + inputObj.id)
        switch (inputObj.type){ 
            case 'select':
                spanObj.innerHTML = inputObj.options[inputObj.selectedIndex].value; 
                break;  
            case 'text':    
            default:
                spanObj.innerHTML = inputObj.value; 
                break;       
        }           
        inputObj.style.display = 'none';
        spanObj.style.display = '';
    }

    function next_cell(inputObj){   
        next_inputObj = $(inputObj).next('.inputfield');
                console.log(next_inputObj);
        open_input(next_inputObj)
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finished work on my fiddle to highlight the problem

http://jsfiddle.net/k77Ya/6/

```
var next_inputObj = $(inputObj).next('.inputfield');
console.log(next_inputObj.length);
```

Essentially, it boils down to the .next() operator not being able to find the class you've suggested. This is because the .next() operator will look for the next item with the class "inputField" in the  that you're in at that point which, of course, doesn't exist so the .next() operator always returns an empty array.

As an aside, the HTML you posted is missing an opening  tag, but that's not the issue here. If you chain together some .parent() operators, you can get the correct level and go from there e.g.

```
var next_inputObj = $(inputObj).parent().next('.inputfield');
```

EDIT:
It's pretty much there now; you can tab between the two boxes at the top and the two at the bottom. It requires some extra code to navigate to the next  when you've reached the last element in the list.

One of the issues was that pressing tab fires a blur event which was affecting the ability to tab between inputs on the page. I'd recommend preventing this functionality by calling the preventDefault() method on the event as below. To implement this, I used the jQuery event handlers as you were replicating code in your inputs - documentation found here: http://api.jquery.com/blur/ and http://api.jquery.com/keydown/

event.preventDefault();

This should now provide a working solution, hope that helps!

Comment: >As an aside, the HTML you posted is missing an opening tag<br />I tired to just show what was need to explain my problem<br />>This should now provide a working solution, hope that helps!<br />Yes it really did help, in fact I didn't expect such an elaborate answer so thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use [nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k77Ya/3/)

```
function open_input(inputObj){
    if(!$(inputObj).length) return;
    var spanObj = document.getElementById('s' + inputObj.id)    
    inputObj.style.display = 'block';
    spanObj.style.display = 'none';
    inputObj.click();
    setTimeout(function(){inputObj.focus()},0);
}

function next_cell(inputObj){   
    console.log(inputObj);
    var next_inputObj = $(inputObj).closest('td').nextAll('td').find('.inputfield')[0];
    open_input(next_inputObj)

}
```

Comment: Didn't help still just returning [].

Comment: There is an error somewhere else because element is find here: http://jsfiddle.net/DW7wm/

Comment: $(inputObj).closest('td').nextAll('td').find('.inputfield').first()[0]

Comment: @loxdog ya, or just `$(inputObj).closest('td').nextAll('td').find('.inputfield')[0]` I have just hard time to understand code logic here, too many inline scripts which make code unreadable

Comment: Doesn't tab between all the boxes, but that's an issue with the original code. I've finished tweaking the fiddle and... it works! http://jsfiddle.net/k77Ya/6/

Comment: I was thinking you only want to tab on same TR, sorry